# 1.4GB of E-Mail, Thunderbird all e-mails blank when opened

Tags: email, thunderbird, inbox

A friend of mine imported 1.4 GB of e-mail from Outlook 2003 into Thunderbird Portable about a year ago. He never actually verified the import was successful and no longer has access to the Outlook 2003 files. Now, when he opens Thunderbird, all e-mails open up as blank. I have verified the inbox file is 1.4 GB so the data is still there.

So far I have tried rebuilding the inbox index and tried uploading the e-mail to a new Gmail account using IMAP. Rebuilding the index did nothing and very few e-mails were uploaded to the Gmail account.

Does anyone have any suggestions for repairing the inbox file or are there any programs that will repair the file or convert/import the inbox file into another program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: [ImportExportTools](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) extension to re-import it in another account, or to export it as mbox/eml/text/html/csv