# Corrupted Thunderbird inbox from old computer

Tags: email, thunderbird, file-corruption, inbox

I have a old Thunderbird inbox from an old computer. Upon import with importExportTool, Thunderbird tells me that the file is corrupted. Following Q&A on thunderbird's forums I have tried a lot of different solutions. The last and following with the most interesting findings:

I have opened the file with [010 editor](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/) but the file is a 3GB collection of 0's.
[image]

Is this a known problem? And what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-complicating it.  The Inbox is just a text file.  Forget the import-export tool;  just copy the file Inbox to the mail folder location on the new system.  Then open Thunderbird and, if the file doesn't rebuild its index automatically, right-click it to Compact, which will force it to rebuild the index.  Just make sure that you only copy the Inbox file & not its index, though, and you won't even need to do that -- Tbird will rebuild the index as soon as it notes that its missing.

Comment: Have tried :) Creates an empty index file

Comment: The only way that should ever happen is if the Inbox file is somehow damaged.  But if it was working on the old computer, it should still work on the new one.  It is just a text file.  Are you giving Tbird the time to rebuild the index for the file?  Does it even try to do so?  Perhaps a better way to do this is to rename the file something other than "Inbox" and place it at the same level, so it in essence becomes a "folder".  Also going back to "import", that's really for data that was created with a different mail client, because Tbird keeps its data files in their basic text format.

Comment: Also see the response of fluxtendu here http://superuser.com/questions/85254/1-4gb-of-e-mail-thunderbird-all-e-mails-blank-when-opened?rq=1  as that solution may work for you too.